# How to get multiple rows into one line as a string? 

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables "one to many":

Table1

```
ID    Name
1     Abe
2     David
3     Orly
```

Table2

```
ID    email
1     a@zz.com
1     ab@zz.com
1     abe@zz.com
2     dav@zz.com
2     d@zz.com
3     orly@zz.com
3     o@zz.com
```

I need an output like this:

```
1 Abe a@zz.com, ab@zz.com, abe@zz.com
2 David dav@zz.com, d@zz.com
3 Orly orly@zz.com, o@zz.com
```

I know this won't work, because the inner SELECT is not a single string:

```
SELECT 
    ID, Name, 
    (SELECT email FROM Table2  WHERE Table2.ID = Table1.ID) AS emails 
FROM Table1
```

I tried to apply:

```
DECLARE @emails VARCHAR(999)

SELECT [ID],[Name], 
     (SELECT @emails = COALESCE(@emails + ', ', '') + [email] 
      FROM Table2) AS 'emails' 
FROM Table1
```

but with no luck.

How should this be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide expected output

Comment: [Coalesce (see prior Q&A)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One of the neatest ways to achieve this is to combine For XML Path and STUFF as follows:

```
SELECT
    ID, Name, 
    Emails = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + Email FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.ID = Table1.ID
        FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')
FROM Table1
```

Comment: And, you can add `group by ID, Name` to eliminate the extra rows.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table1 a
CROSS APPLY --or OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(
        (SELECT ','+b.Email
        FROM    Table2 b
        WHERE   a.ID = b.ID
        FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,2
        ,4000) GroupConcat
) x
```

Results:

```
ID Name  GroupConcat
-- ----- -----------------------------
1  Abe   a@zz.com,ab@zz.com,abe@zz.com
2  David dav@zz.com,d@zz.com
3  Orly  orly@zz.com,o@zz.com
```

Comment: I had to add `distinct` to the outermost `select` to eliminate extra rows.