# Stringify subquery results into main query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have two tables; students and classes.  Each students can have many classes.
I would like to create a query that will print out every student in the following style:
Column 1 the students name and column 2 a string of classes they are in ex "math, history, geology"
I know how to query every student or query all classes but cant seem to wrap my mind around getting them to work together. The SQL used to create the string:

```
DECLARE @classes VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @classes = COALESCE(@classes + ', ', '') + clss.name
FROM
(
SELECT name
FROM classes
where student.id = 1
)clss
SELECT @classes
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get multiple rows into one line as a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958816/how-to-get-multiple-rows-into-one-line-as-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name
    , STUFF ((
        SELECT ', ' + c.name
        FROM classes c
        WHERE c.student_id = s.student_id
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') AS classes
FROM students s
```