# How to create a comma delimited list using SELECT statement from table columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks in advance.

I have a table with values like this

```
class_id Instructor_Name

———————————

1 Joe 

2 Joe 

3 Joe 

1 Judy 

2 Judy 

2 Kevin 

3 Kevin
```

and I want the Result Set like this using SQL statement:

```
id name services (I want)

———————————–

1 Joe, Judy

2 Joe, Judy, KevinC

3 Joe, Kevin
```

How can I get this

Thanks,
Brijesh

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Sever

Comment: Check solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513630/stringify-subquery-results-into-main-query

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` with correlated subquery:

```
select 
    class_id,
    stuff(
        (select ', ' + Instructor_Name from your_table b 
         where a.class_id = b.class_id for xml path('')),
        1, 2, ''
    ) names
from your_table a
group by
    class_id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, GurV, worked like a charm. I was trying to find the previously posted question but was not able to find the right keyword for this. Thanks Again.