# how to loop subquery to return multiple values if they exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i am still learning SQL. I have the following table DeviceType

```
|shopName|Device
---------|-----------
|Shop1   |app1
|Shop1   |app2
|Shop1   |sam1
|Shop2   |app67
|Shop3   |app82
|Shop3   |sam028
```

i am trying to get the following result

```
Shop1|app1|app2|sam1
Shop2|app67
Shop3|app82|sam028
```

my code is as follows:

```
select Shopname,(SELECT device FROM DeviceType where left(SNTxReference,3)='app'     )
from DeviceType
```

but i get Subquery returned more than 1 value

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Is there a maximum of devices per shop?

Comment: @Mureinik i am using MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: SQL is a language, 2012 is a year. MS SQL Server 2012 is a dbms product.

Comment: @ Radim no there is no max, if it fails to find it should stop

Comment: What you are doing is challenging with relational data because it is no longer relational. You will have to use a dynamic pivot for this.

Comment: @SeanLange Or `STUFF` if he wants them pipe delimited and in one column.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by structuring the result set that way, @Tinashe? I'm wondering if it's really necessary or if there might be a better approach.

Comment: I think you are more looking at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958816/how-to-get-multiple-rows-into-one-line-as-a-string